# java.net.ProtocolException: Server redirected too many times (20)

Tags: java, ntlm, java-7

I'm using `NTLM` authentication in my web application similar to [this one](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/Auth.html) to restfully retrieve some data from another domain. It used to work fine.

After JDK 1.7 upgrade, I've started receiving `java.net.ProtocolException: Server redirected too many  times (20)` exception. I don't know if it's happening due to 1.7 upgrade (it could just be a coincidence).

The code is pretty much the same as this:

```
// Install the custom authenticator
Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticator());

// Access the page
try {
    // Create a URL for the desired page
    URL url = new URL("http://hostname:80/index.html");

    // Read all the text returned by the server
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    String str;
    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
        // str is one line of text; readLine() strips the newline character(s)
    }
    in.close();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
} catch (IOException e) {
}

public class MyAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
    // This method is called when a password-protected URL is accessed
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        // Get information about the request
        String promptString = getRequestingPrompt();
        String hostname = getRequestingHost();
        InetAddress ipaddr = getRequestingSite();
        int port = getRequestingPort();

        // Get the username from the user...
        String username = "myusername";

        // Get the password from the user...
        String password = "mypassword";

        // Return the information
        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());
    }
}
```

Could anyone please help me in this regard?

Comment: It's hard to tell anything without the source code.

Comment: It's implemented exactly like the code in http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/Auth.html

Comment: @ManishMulani Do you have find a workaround in the meantime? I have the same problem.